# "Summable Numbers" in C++

Tags: c++, math

The divisors of n can make the number between 1 to n. This is called a summable number. An example is 12. 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12 can be added together in different ways to make the numbers 1 through 12. Now this code gives me all summable numbers from 1 to an user inputed number but it is also giving me some numbers that are not summable such as 14. I am not sure why that is. Where in the code do I have to make a change?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

vector <int> divisors;
vector<int> subsetsResult;
vector<int> subset;

bool isSummableNumber(int num)
{
    if ((num > 1) && (num % 2 != 0))
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i=1; i<=num; i++)
    {
        if (num%i==0)
        {
            divisors.push_back(i);

            int SIZE_OF_DIVISORS_SET = divisors.size();
            double COUNTER_LIMIT     = pow(2, SIZE_OF_DIVISORS_SET) - 1;
            int TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_BITS = 8;

            for (int counter = 1; counter <= COUNTER_LIMIT; counter++)
            {
                int currentValue = counter;

                for (int bitIndex = 0; bitIndex < TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_BITS; bitIndex++)
                {
                    if (currentValue & 000001)
                    {
                        subset.push_back(divisors[bitIndex]);
                    }

                    currentValue = currentValue >> 1;
                }

                int sum = 0;
                for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = subset.begin() ; it != subset.end(); ++it)
                    sum += *it;

                if (sum >= 1 && sum <= num)
                {
                    subsetsResult.push_back(sum);
                }

            }
            subsetsResult;

            int counter = 1;
            for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = subsetsResult.begin(); it != subsetsResult.end(); ++it)
            {
                if (counter != *it)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                counter += 1;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Enter a Positive Integer: " ;
    cin >> num;

    for (int i=1; i<=num; i++)
    {
        if (isSummableNumber(i))
            cout << i << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The term you're looking for is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number

Comment: @Ben 12 is not a perfect number.

Comment: @Alan: You are correct. I retract my comment.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What happens when you step through it in a debugger?

Comment: Where did you take the algorithm (not the code!) from?

Comment: Such numbers are called [practical numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_number). There is [a simple and good algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_number#Characterization_of_practical_numbers) to determine if `n` is a practical number.

Comment: A big problem is that divisors, subsetsResult and subset are not emptied out before the second and further calls to isSummableNumber. That would work a lot better if they were local variables in the function isSummableNumber.

Comment: Another problem is that you will only ever add the eight smallest divisors. And that you assume that you will find the sums in the right order. Which cannot possibly work if 1, 2 and 3 are divisors because you will push the sum 3 twice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd calculate the set of all numbers from 0 to n that are the sums of divisors that you found so far. std::vector  with a size of n + 1 will do fine. Initially, only element 0 is set. Then if you find another divisor d (in pseudo-code)

```
for (i = n; i >= d; --i)
    if (resultset contains i - d)
        add i to the result set.
```

Finally you check whether the set contains all numbers from 0 to n.

Answer (score 0):

This does not do anything: `subsetsResult;`

Also, don't you get a compiler warning about paths in your function that do not return a value? There is a missing `return false;` and the end of the function (and maybe and assertion if that return should never be reached).

Comment: My compiler is not showing any errors. Everything -to the compiler- seems to be in order. After some more trials, 14 is the only number that is coming up that is not a summable number which is interesting as well.

Comment: Anyway you should look into those two issues.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're searching divisor combinations before you've even found all the divisors.  That's not a good idea, and it likely is hiding your problem.

Either wait until all divisors are found and then iterate the 2**k sums they produce, or else when each new divisor is found, produce sums from the already-known sums and the new divisor, and skip the bit manipulation.  For example:

```
sums = {0}
N=14, i=1, N%i == 0, sums += i + sums => sums = {0, 1+0}
N=14, i=2, N%i == 0, sums += i + sums => sums = {0, 1, 2+0, 2+1}
N=14, i=3, N%i == 2
...
N=14, i=7, N%i == 0, sums += i + sums => sums = {0, 1, 2, 3, 7+0, 7+1, 7+2, 7+3}
```

Now since 4 < N and 4 is not a member of sums, exclude 14